# Python: inverse empirical cumulative distribution function (ECDF)?

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

We can create the ECDF with

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution import ECDF
ecdf = ECDF([3, 3, 1, 4])
```

and obtain then ECDF at point with

```
ecdf(x)
```

However, what if I want to know the x for percentile 97.5% ?

From `http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution.ECDF.html?highlight=ecdf`, it seems like not been implemented.

Is there any way to do this? Or any other libraries?

Comment: You might be able to get somewhere with `sc.stats.rv_discrete(values=([3, 3, 1, 4],[0.25]*4)).ppf(0.975)`, but it seems buggy (try with `0.5` instead to see what I mean)

Comment: simply solve the equation `ecdf(x)=0.975` using a numerical solver.

Comment: Can't you apply [`monotone_fn_inverter`](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution.monotone_fn_inverter.html) to the ECDF?

Comment: Oh, dear, step functions don't have inverses, do they? Could we agree to define the function you want as, say, the minimum x for which Pr{x<=p}?

Comment: @BillBell yes, that's can be the definition of the inverse of CDF. I can probably create on my own. Just want to know the best practice in doing it.

Answer (score 12):

Since the empirical CDF just places mass of 1/n at each data point, the 97.5th quantile is just the data point that is bigger than 97.5% of all the other points. To find this value, you can simply sort the data in ascending order and find the 0.975n-th largest value.

```
sample = [1, 5, 2, 10, -19, 4, 7, 2, 0, -1]
n = len(sample)
sort = sorted(sample)
print sort[int(n * 0.975)]
```

Which produces:

```
10
```

Since we remember than for discrete distributions (like the empirical cdf), the quantile function is defined [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJtXR.gif) , we realize that we have to take the 0.975n-th (rounded up) largest value.

Answer (score 8):

This is my suggestion. Linear interpolation because dfs are only effectively estimated from fairly large samples anyway. The interpolating line segments can be obtained because their endpoints occur at distinct values in the sample.

```
import statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution as edf
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample = [1,4,2,6,5,5,3,3,5,7]
sample_edf = edf.ECDF(sample)

slope_changes = sorted(set(sample))

sample_edf_values_at_slope_changes = [ sample_edf(item) for item in slope_changes]
inverted_edf = interp1d(sample_edf_values_at_slope_changes, slope_changes)

x = np.linspace(0.1, 1)
y = inverted_edf(x)
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', x, y, 'b-')
plt.show()

print ('97.5 percentile:', inverted_edf(0.975))
```

It produces the following output,

```
97.5 percentile: 6.75
```

and this graph.
[image: inverted empirical cdf]

Comment: I think this is very helpful for using few points. Still, in my actual case, I have a lot of points (>10000), so it may be a little bit over-kill for me.

Comment: i don't think it's necessary to remove duplicates from ```sample``` to compute again an **ECDF** to sample from. ```interp1d``` does the trick, especially if one uses [```kind='linear'```](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html). therefore just do ```inverted_edf = interp1d( edf.ECDF(sample)(sample), sample )```.

Answer (score 6):

[`numpy.quantile(x, q=.975)`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html) will return the value along array x at which has ecdf 0.975.

Similarly, there is [`pandas.quantile(q=0.97)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) for Series/DataFrames.

Comment: You must be careful here because numpy percentile and quantile functions only interpolate (by default linearly) the interval between the minimum and the maximum of x, so it's not the same as the inverse of the empirical cdf.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that it interpolates, but between the 2 points around the x you are using, not for the minimum and maximum of x.

From Numpy documentation

The optional `method` parameter specifies the method to use when the
desired quantile lies between two indexes `i` and `j = i + 1`.

From Pandas documentation

interpolation : {'linear', 'lower', 'higher', 'midpoint', 'nearest'}
This optional parameter specifies the interpolation method to use,
when the desired quantile lies between two data points `i` and `j`:

```
        * linear: `i + (j - i) * fraction`, where `fraction` is the
```

Comment: You should use `>` quoting when referring to e.g. documentation contents.